# Move data from PostgreSQL to AWS S3 and analyze with RedShift Spectrum

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a big amount of PostgreSQL tables with different schemas and the massive amount of data inside them.

I'm unable to do the data analytics right now because the data amount is quite large - a few TB of data and PostgreSQL is not able to process queries in a reasonable amount of time.

I'm thinking about the following approach - I'll process all of my PostgreSQL tables with Apache Spark, load the DataFrames and store them as the Parquet files in AWS S3. Then I'll use RedShift Spectrum in order to query the information stored inside of these PARQUET files.

First of all, I'd like to ask - will this solution work at all?

And the second - will RedShift Spectrum be able to automatically create EXTERNAL tables from these Parquet files without additional schema specification(even when the original PostgreSQL tables contain the unsupported data types by AWS RedShift)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Redshift Spectrum pretty much supports same datatypes as Redshift itself.
2. Redshift Spectrum creates cluster of compute nodes behind the scenes. The size of cluster is based on number of actual Redshift Cluster nodes, so if you plan to create 1 node Redshift cluster, Spectrum will run pretty slow.
3. As you noted in comments, you can use Athena to query the data, and it will be better option in your case instead of Spectrum. But Athena has several limitations, like 30 min run time, memory consumption etc. So if you plan to do complicated queries with several joins, it can just not work.
4. Redshift Spectrum can't create external tables without provided structure.
5. Best solution in your case will be to use Spark (on EMR, or Glue) to transform the data, Athena to query it, and if Athena can't do specific query - use SparkSQL on same data. You can use Glue, but running jobs on EMR on Spot Instances will be more flexible and cheaper. EMR clusters comes with EMRFS, which gives you the ability to use S3 almost transparently instead of HDFS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The biggest issue right now that the database contains thousands of different tables with different schemas and it looks like near to impossible to write the ETL scripts for each of them. So, the idea is to save all of these tables into the Apache Parquet files(via Spark on EMR), then automatically create the external tables in Glue Data Catalog by Data Crawler auto-discovery and built-In Parquet  Classifiers. Then I hope I'll be able to use AWS RedShift Spectrum or AWS Athena with the tables defined in Glue Data Catalog. What do you think, will it work in this way?

Comment: Or, as you have mentioned, instead of RedShift Spectrum or Athena, use the AWS Glue Data Catalog as the Metastore for Spark SQL and connect Looker or Tableau BI tools via JDBC to EMR Spark Thrift Server?

Comment: Redshift Spectrum will be an bad option. Also i have no clue about connectivity of BI tools you've mentioned to Spark Thrift or Glue. But Glue Data Catalog + Crawler + Athena (and maybe EMR) will most probably work for you. But if you have some non atomic types in your PostgreSQL, please check if Presto (Athena pretty much just a wrapper around it) supports them.

Answer (score 0):

[AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/) might be interesting as an option for you. It is both a hosted version of Spark, with some AWS specific addons and a Data Crawler + Data Catalogue.

It can crawl unstructured data such as Parquet files and figure out the structure. Which then allows you to export it to AWS RedShift in structured form if needed.

See [this blog post](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/postgresql-jdbc-aws-glue.rst) on how to connect it to a postgres database using JDBC to move data from Postgres to S3.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, looks like Data Crawler + Data Catalogue should do the work. Also, instead of RedShift, I can use AWS Athena